# Conectarme a una red WiFi conocida y comprobación

Tags: java, android

El tema es que si que había logrado que se conectara pero solo si no tengo otras redes WiFi guardadas cerca. Lo que quiero es que se conecte a la Raspberry Pi y compruebe que realmente es esa network para continuar con los procesos, pero se me conecta todo el rato mi red de casa y no hace caso al WifiConfig. Os dejo el codigo. Siempre me muestra REINTENTAR porque realiza el equals con "Orange" y "RasPi".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String ssid;
private WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
private WifiInfo wifiInfo;
private String connectedID,myssid;
private TextView textView;
private Button rebutton;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rebutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rebutton);


    if(connect()){
        textView.setText("CONECTADO!");
    }else{
        textView.setText("REINTENTAR");
    }



    rebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
public boolean connect(){
    ssid = "RasPi";
    myssid="\""+ssid+"\"";
    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
    wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Log.d("TAG",myssid);
    if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        Log.d("TAG","WiFi encendido");
    }
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    Log.d("TAG",wifiConfig.SSID);
    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
    esperar(4)
    Log.d("TAG","Conectando");
    wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    connectedID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
    Log.d("TAG","comprobando "+connectedID+"="+myssid);
    if(connectedID.equals(myssid)){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }


}
public void esperar (int segundos) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep (segundos*1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TAG","esperar falla");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba obteniendo una lista de las redes, y conectando a la red que deseas:

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
 for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(myssid)) {
         wifiManager.disconnect();
         wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
         wifiManager.reconnect();               
         break;
    }           
 }
```